# subprocess python - non zero exception

Tags: python, subprocess

I would like to run the subprocess.check_output method for my python script.

```
try:
        logger.info('Loading URL ' + line)
        wp_output = subprocess.checkout(['ruby', PATH + '/wpscan.rb', '--url', line, '--enumerate',
            'vp', '--enumerate', 'vt'])
        print wp_output
        logger.info(wp_output)
        return wp_output.strip()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        raise
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
        logger.exception('ERROR - Problem occurred while using wpscan.')
```

the exception:

```
 File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command '[u'ruby', u'./wpscan/wpscan.rb', u'--url', 'www.website.de', u'--enumerate', u'vp', u'--enumerate', u'vt']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

if I run check_output I get a non-zero exception, if I use only "subprocess.call" I get as result "print wp_output" only the int 1??

What I am doing wrong? I would like to get the output as a string (wp_output).

Comment: Are you getting any error when you directly run that command from terminal?

Comment: @AnandSKumar  no, it works fine

Comment: ruby wpscan.rb --url www.mywebsite.de --enumerate vp --enumerate vt - works perfect

Comment: What is `PATH` variable ?

Comment: config.ini [PATHS]
path = ./wpscan

Comment: can you show the code where `PATH` variable is set ?

Comment: # Config for the PATH
CONFIG = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
CONFIG.read('config.ini')
PATH = CONFIG.get('PATHS', 'path')

Comment: Try without the `PATH +` also, change `'/wpscan.rb'` to `'wpscan.rb'`

Comment: it still doesn't works wp_output = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/ruby', 'wpscan/wpscan.rb', '--url', line, '--enumerate', 'vp', '--enumerate', 'vt'])

Comment: No , not `'wpscan/wpscan.rb'` , give full path to the ruby file, try hardcoding it

Comment: that is my path. $ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby  -- wpscan/wpscan.rb

Comment: i mean't `wpscan.rb` file, full path for that as well

Comment: still same exception

Answer (score 1):

When you run `subprocess.call` is returns an int that represents the exit code of the program. Typically a 0 means everything ran fine, and other numbers, such as your 1, indicate an error.

`subprocess.check_output` will specifically treat an error as an exception within python itself, and raise it, which leads to your result.

If you want the string output whether it was an error or a success, use `Popen`.

```
command = ['ruby', PATH + '/wpscan.rb', '--url', line, '--enumerate',
        'vp', '--enumerate', 'vt']
wp_output = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wp_output = wp_output.communicate()
print wp_output
```

Using `Popen` with `subprocess.PIPE` and then running `communicate` on it will gives you a tuple containing the text that your command returned, whether it's an error or not.

Comment: cool, thanks :) hmm, but why it has a error? I use everything correct :/

Comment: At a guess, I think Python is running different environment variables. That means it can't find `ruby` just with the name. Try using the exact path to wherever the Ruby executable is as that first parameter, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: but if ruby can't be find, it would never perform the code, but it performed the wpscan and at the end I get the exception

Comment: Are you sure it performed it or are you assuming that it did because the script continued running? An error in a subprocess doesn't actually interrupt a script the same way an exception in Python normally does if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: If I use subprocess.call I see for example the full code at the command line.

Comment: my ruby is in /usr/bin so I change now the code like this "wp_output = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/ruby', PATH + '/wpscan.rb', '--url', line, '--enumerate', 'vp', '--enumerate', 'vt'])" I get still the same exception

Comment: Oh, you may also need to change your `PATH` to be an absolute path instead of relative.

Comment: wp_output = subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/ruby', 'wpscan/wpscan.rb', '--url', line, '--enumerate', 'vp', '--enumerate', 'vt']) - still same problem

Comment: what is if I don't want a tuple but the string!? (for the Popen method)

Comment: You can reference it just like a list, just check `wp_output[0]` and `wp_output[1]`. Normal output is in 0, errors are in 1.

Comment: yes, but the format is so terrible - it puts the whole output in one string :( for example "m[+]\x1b[0m Started: Mon Jul 13 12:31:40 2015\n\n\x1b[32m[+]\x1b[0m robots.txt available under: 'http://www.website.de/robots.txt'\n\x1b[33m[!]\x1b[0m The WordPress 'http://www.website.de/readme.html' file exists exposing a version number\n\x1b[32m[+]\x1b[0m Interesting header: SERVER: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)\n\x1b[32m[+]\x1b[0m Interesting header: SET-COOKIE: wfvt_1342818671=55a3938dafb99;"

Answer (score 0):

This is an addon to SuperBiasedMan's comment. It will be nice to redirect the stderr too as errors usually appear in stderr than stdout.

```
command = ['ruby', PATH + '/wpscan.rb', '--url', line, '--enumerate',
    'vp', '--enumerate', 'vt']
wp_proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
wp_output, wp_error = wp_proc.communicate()

if wp_error != '':
    print wp_error
else:
    print wp_output
```